ASM x86 (64-bit) printing extra bytes in Hello World
The Expected output is Hello World but the result is something like Hello Worldhi. Probably it is an issue with len variable. I have a little bit experience in x86_32 and I was shifting towards x86_64 but got error in Hello World.
BITS 64
section .data
    text db "Hello World", 0  ; Add a null byte at the end
    text2 db "hi"
    len equ $-text

section .text
global _start
_start:
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, text
    mov rdx, len
    syscall

    mov rax, 60
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall

Just in case
nasm -f elf64 -o build/main.o src/main.asm
ld -m elf_x86_64 build/main.o -o main
I am using these commands to make object file and then linking.
Thansk in advance.

Since you have put the len equ $-text after the hi that will be included in the length. Move the equ up one line so it's directly after the Hello World. Note that you don't need the terminating zero since you specify the length explicitly.

The write system call takes a pointer+length.  It doesn't care about zero bytes as a string terminator; that's why it takes a length as well as a pointer, allowing it to work with binary data.  If you run ./main | hexdump -C, you'll see that the output includes the zero byte.  And no newline because you didn't include one.

Anyway, sort of a duplicate of How does $ work in NASM, exactly? except for the misconception that the 0 byte would do anything.


The low‑level write system call copies whatever data from memory to the specified file.
It does not heed a NULL‑byte and it will attempt to read data from memory that does not belong to you (your application) if you tell it to do so.
In an ancient revision of the manual page for write, the function signature indeed indicated char*, which conventionally means a NULL‑terminated string, but this has been amended since.
Actually the output is Hello World, null byte, hi.
You can render the null byte visible by piping the output into, for example, hd (hexdump).
./a.out | hd

That is 14 bytes in total.
It is 14 because 14 is the value of len.
The value of len is 14 because the absolute difference between the assembly memory address at the location of the label text and the memory address right before the occurrence of $ in the equ constant definition is 14.

